# Using LESS, how do I reference a class in the separate font-awesome .less file?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, less, webfonts

### Background

- I am using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) LESS source with [LessJS](http://lesscss.org/)
- I'm using [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).less (referenced from within Bootstrap.less)
- I've removed the icons section from bootstrap so they don't conflict.
- I have a site.less file which I also reference from within Bootstrap that contains some site-specific styling.

### Goal

I would like to be able to do something along the following lines in my site.css file:

```
.feedbackItemIconPraise
{
    .icon-thumbs-up; //class included in font-awesome.less
    color:Green;
}
```

### Problem

When I try the approach above, I get the following error:

[image]

This error makes sense; I'm just not sure how best to correct it without creating an additional import of font-awesome.less in my site.less (which I imagine would be its own issue).

**To clarify:** Per comments below: I have a class name that I'm using from a Knockout viewmodel. (for example, if "Praise" is selected, it will apply the class "FeedbackItemPraise"). If FeedbackItemPraise is selected, I'd like it to apply the .icon-thumbs-up class from font-awesome (which displays the icon via a web font) and then also make the color green.

### What I have so far

Bootstrap.less customization (only relevant parts shown):

```
//Sean's customizations
@import "background.less"; // Background images and colors 
@import "font-awesome.less"; // Font Awesome font (SK 2012/09/04)
@import "site.less"; // site-specific LESS
```

Class within site.less:

```
.feedbackItemIconPraise
{
    .icon-thumbs-up; //class included in font-awesome.less
    color:Green;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to derive `feedbackItemIconPraise` from `icon-thumbs-up`

Comment: Hi Luke! To clarify: I have a class name that I'm using from a Knockout viewmodel. (for example, if "Praise" is selected, it will apply the class "FeedbackItemPraise"). If FeedbackItemPraise is selected, I'd like it to apply the .icon-thumbs-up class from font-awesome (which displays the icon via a web font) and then also make the color green.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATED

Upon looking at Font-Awesome again, looks like they have now included mixins for the icons. See the following two files.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/variables.less

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/less/mixins.less

Use like:

```
.feedbackItemIconPraise
{
    .icon(@thumbs-up-alt)
    color:Green;
}
```

### ORIGINAL

If you look at font-awesome.less you will see that class doesn't exist, it's actually `.icon-thumbs-up:before`. Unfortunately you can't use pseudo classes as mixins, eg `.icon-thumbs-up:before;`.

You will need to modify your font-awesome.less file (or just add this class, or just put `content: "\f087";` directly where it needs to go) so there is a non `:before` version:

```
.icon-thumbs-up:before            { content: "\f087"; }
.icon-thumbs-up                   { content: "\f087"; }
```

Then apply this concept:

```
.feedbackItemIconPraise {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 90px;
    padding-top: 7px;

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;

    &:before {
        .icon-thumbs-up;
    }

}
```

Seems Font-Awesome icons have to use the `:before` pseudo for them to show up.

Demo: http://pulse-dev.com/files/stackoverflow/fontawesomeclass/

Comment: Patrick, if I'm already including both site.less and font-awesome.less in my bootstrap.less file, wouldn't it be counter-productive to also include font-awesome.less in my site.less file? Seems like it would lead to conflicts.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide some more information so you can see how I'm laying things out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a spud. It was supposed to be `@import "font-awesome.less";
`. Bad c+p. See my updated answer anyway.

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to apply the icon via the LESS file? See second edit.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. If you statically apply that to any li or div or i element, it works. So what I'm trying to do is apply a class in less that also contains that class, so that I can keep the names in line with my ViewModel (which is automatically generating the classname that needs to be applied based on an item that is selected). So my question is why, if i have everything referenced from bootstrap.less and it works manually, can I not use the LESS syntax to apply a class that's located in another less file.

Comment: @SeanKilleen - wondering if you got a better solution working?

Comment: Hi Patrick, let me know if this blog post I did answers it for you: http://www.seankilleen.com/2012/12/how-to-quickly-update-mvc4-project-with.html If so, I may link here and summarize. I'd given upon this specific question but it seems that the answer may be meant to be more generic.

Comment: @SeanKilleen Nah I was interested in the specific question. Hoping that you may have found a better/simpler way than my method! Might just have to hold out hope that pseudo classes become valid mixins in LESS.

Comment: I haven't gotten to dig into this in some time but will likely be reopening it soon in which case I'll dig in deep and post an answer if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another solution to this, but I combine my scripts into a single file (automatically) before running it through the LESS compiler. This allows me to define variables and mixins up front that can be used in any of my LESS files.

The [online documentation](http://lesscss.org/) does mention that LESS can include the `@import` files, making the variables and mixins available. You may need to ensure that you are on the latest version of the compiler and if the import files are organised in a folder structure, you may need to tell the compiler where to search.

```
var parser = new(less.Parser)({
    paths: ['.', './lib'], // Specify search paths for @import directives
    filename: 'style.less' // Specify a filename, for better error messages
});
```

Comment: Sohnee: This is what I'm doing, which is why it's strange. The bootstrap.less file is the one I use. It has an import of font-awesome.less and site.less. Within site.less, I'm referring to a class that is part of font-awesome.less, and so I'd expect that to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @goober I'm actually combining them into a single physical file, rather than using an `@import`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying! I read too hastily. I'll look into this as a possible solution for sure.

Comment: @goober no problem - added a note about `@import` to the answer.